# Solution of $y''+4y=\cos^2t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the solution, which is supposed to be

$y(t)=c_2\sin(2t)+c_1\cos(2t)+\frac{t\sin(2t)}{8}+\frac{\cos^2(t)}{4}$,

but I'm doing something wrong along the way and I can't figure out what I did.  I was hoping someone would be able to find my mistake for me.  I'll show what I've gotten:

First I got the complementary solution $y_c(t)=c_1\cos(2x)+c_2\cos(2x)$

I then used the particular solution $y_p=A+B\cos(2t)+C\sin(2t)$ - I'm guessing this is where my error occurs, but I don't see what's wrong with it.

I derived it two times and got $y_p''=-4B\cos2t-4C\sin(2t)$

I plugged it into the original equation (assuming $\cos^2t$ is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}$) and then tried to solve the problem, at which point I found myself running in circles:

$\sin2t(-4C-4C)+\cos2t(-4B+4B)+4A=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Can anyone help me find my mistake(s)?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: $e^{\pm 2x}$ is not a solution to $y''+4y=0$.

Comment: Thank you.  I got $y_c(t)=c_1cos(2x)+c_2cos(2x)$ the second time around, I will put it into my question.  I'm pretty sure I'm still doing something else wrong though.

Comment: The characteristic equation associated with $y'' + 4y = 0$ is $\lambda^2 + 4 = 0$. Notice your inhomogeneous term $\cos^2 t$ can be rewritten as $\frac12 (1+ \cos(2t)) = \frac14 ( 2 + e^{2it} + e^{-2it} )$ and contains Fourier components of angular frequency $0, \pm 2i$. Since $\pm 2i$ are simple roots of the characteristic equation, the generic form of the particular solution has the form $a + \color{red}{t} (b \cos(2t) + c\sin(2t))$ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You figured out the issue with:

$$y_c(t) = c_1 \cos 2t + c_2 \sin 2t$$

For the particular solution, some care is needed given the homogeneous (complementary) solution. We expand the $\cos^2 2t$ term as:

$$\cos^2 2t = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1 +\cos 2t\right)$$

Now, we notice that this has a common term with the homogeneous term, so we multiply the particular solution by $t$ to account for that. Thus, we choose a particular solution as:

$$y_p(t) = a + b~ t \cos 2t + c~ t \sin 2t$$

Now, substitute and solve for $a$, $b$ and $c$.

You should get:

$$a = \dfrac{1}{8}, b = 0, c = \dfrac{1}{8}$$

Your final solution will be:

$$y(t) = y_c(t) + y_p(t)$$

Comment: Thank you.  I redid my work several times and got $a$ and $b$ correct, but I keep getting all sorts of weird numbers for $c$.  I'll try to redo my problem a few more times.  If I still can't get $c$ to work out, I might ask a question about some of the nitty-gritty calculations if that's all right with you.

Comment: No problem! Give a go and if you get stuck, give a yell!

Comment: Very well written and +1 for the encouraging spirit!

Answer (score 2):

The complementary solution is 
$$y_c(t) = c_1\cos(2t) + c_2\sin(2t).$$
Notice that $t\mapsto \cos^2(t)$ is in the linear span of this solution.  What do you do in those cases?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected that error.  However, I know I've botched up somewhere else too.
In regards to your question, do you mean that I need to set my $y_p=A+Btcos2t+Ctcos2t$?  I notice that I have duplication now because I made a mistake in my complementary solution.

Comment: Give it a whirl.

Comment: I redid the problem and got $B=0$, $C=\frac{1}{4}$, and $A=\frac{1}{8}$.  Is this correct?  If not, I'll go back and review my work and post what I did if I can't find where I went wrong.
Actually, this looks wrong.  I'll go rework my problem.

Comment: Found out where I went wrong.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{y'' + 4y = \cos^{2}t:\ {\large ?}}$

> Let's define $\mu \equiv y' + 2y\ic$ such that
> $$
> \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
> \cos^{2}\pars{t} = y'' + 4y = \pars{\mu'' - 2y'\ic} + 4\,{\mu - y' \over 2\ic}
> = 
> \mu' -2\mu\ic
> \quad\imp\quad
> \mu' -2\mu\ic = \cos^{2}\pars{t}
> \tag{1}
> $$
> $$
> \mbox{Notice that}\quad y = {1 \over 2}\,\Im\mu \tag{2}
> $$

Multiply both members of the last equation in $\pars{1}$ by the factor
$\expo{-2\ic t}$:
$$
\expo{-2\ic t}\mu' -2\mu\expo{-2\ic t}\ic = \expo{-2\ic t}\cos^{2}\pars{t}
\quad\imp\quad
\totald{\pars{\expo{-2\ic t}\mu}}{t} = \expo{-2\ic t}\cos^{2}\pars{t}
$$

$$
\expo{-2\ic t}\mu = \int\expo{-2\ic t}\cos^{2}\pars{t}\,\dd t + A
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
A \in {\mathbb C}\ \mbox{is a}\ {\it\mbox{constant}}.
\tag{3}
$$
Also
\begin{align}
\int\expo{-2\ic t}\cos^{2}\pars{t}\,\dd t
&=
\int\expo{-2\ic t}\,{1 + \cos\pars{2t} \over 2}\,\dd t
=
{1 \over 2}\bracks{%
\int\expo{-2\ic t}\,\dd t + {1 \over 2}\pars{1 + \int\expo{-4\ic t}\,\dd t}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 4}\,\ic\expo{-2\ic t} + {1 \over 4}\,t + {1 \over 16}\,\ic\expo{-4\ic t}
\end{align}
By replacing this integration in $\pars{3}$ we get:
$$
\mu
=
{1 \over 4}\ic + {1 \over 4}\,t\expo{2it} + {1 \over 16}\,\ic\expo{-2\ic t}
+
A\expo{2it} 
$$
Then $\pars{~\mbox{see Eq.}\ \pars{2}~}$
$$
y
=
{1 \over 8} + {1 \over 8}\,t\sin\pars{2t} + {1 \over 32}\,\cos\pars{2t}
+
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\bracks{A\expo{2it}} 
$$
Let's write $A = B/4 + 2\pars{C - 1/32}\,\ic$ where $B$ and $C$ are constants
$\pars{~B, C \in {\mathbb R}~}$:
$$
y
=
{1 \over 8} + {1 \over 8}\,t\sin\pars{2t} + {1 \over 32}\,\cos\pars{2t}
+
{1 \over 8}\,B\sin\pars{2t} + \pars{C - {1 \over 32}}\cos\pars{2t} 
$$

\begin{align}
&
\\[1cm]
\\
{\large y\pars{t}}
&{\large =
{1 \over 8} + {1 \over 8}\pars{t + B}\sin\pars{2t} + C\cos\pars{2t}}
\\[3mm]&
{\large B\ \mbox{and}\ C\ \mbox{are determined by the initial conditions.}}
\end{align}
Let's check it:
\begin{align}
y'\pars{t}
&=
{1 \over 8}\,\sin\pars{2t} + {1 \over 4}\pars{t + B}\cos\pars{2t}
-
2C\sin\pars{2t}
\\[3mm]
y''\pars{t}
&=
{1 \over 4}\,\cos\pars{2t} + {1 \over 4}\cos\pars{2t}
-
{1 \over 2}\pars{t + B}\sin\pars{2t}
-
4C\cos\pars{2t}
\\
{\large y''\pars{t} + 4y\pars{t}}
&=
{1 \over 4}\,\cos\pars{2t} + {1 \over 4}\cos\pars{2t}
+
{1 \over 2}
=
{1 \over 2}\bracks{1 + \cos\pars{2t}} = {\large\cos^{2}\pars{t}}
\end{align}